# How can I display the value of a field in Wordpress + PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, compiler-errors

I installed this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) and created a custom fields called "imagine"

Field appeared in the admin panel, insert images but nothing is display...

I tried to use this code but unfortunately still does not work.

```
<div class="selectat">
    <div>
        <?php $variable = the_field( 'imagine' );?>
        <?php echo $variable;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is wrong parameter? I put one image to understand more clearly what I do.

[image]

This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_field() in /home/dgsite81/public_html/bagel/bagel/wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/archive.php on line 23
```

Simply want to display the value of a field ... I use correctly function or should another?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`the_field()` is part of [ACF Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and you've used [types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/)
So better to use their functions,

For example:

```
$trainer_email_address = types_render_field("email",array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";"));
```

In your case,

```
$variable = types_render_field("imagine", array("output"=>"html") );
```

[Read More Here](https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/displaying-wordpress-custom-fields/)